# Regex in Web.config Rewrite Rules for partial lowercase URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, web-config

For SEO I want my URLs to be consistent but I don't want that to affect any query parameters. So for example:
These URLs:

- https://www.eXample.com/blog/article/
- https://www.example.com/Blog/article/
- https://www.example.com/blog/aRtiCle/
- https://www.eXamPle.com/bLoG/aRtiClE/

should all become:

- https://www.example.com/blog/article/

However this one:

- https://www.eXamPle.com/bLoG/aRtiClE/?q=aRtGHg

should be:

- https://www.example.com/blog/article/?q=aRtGHg

I kind of have something that works sometimes with this:

```
    <rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="([A-Z]+)(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:1}{R:2}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: I get a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error with that

Comment: I don't have time to test at the moment, but you can probably do something with [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#using-back-references-in-rewrite-rules).

Comment: It seems you should change `ignoreCase="false"` to `ignoreCase="true"`, then just use `url="(.*)"` and `url="{ToLower:{R:1}}"`.

Comment: Wiktor that causes the same `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments by `John`,I got it to work like this:

```
    <rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*?)(\?.*|$)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:1}}{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```